# Redefine the abstract environment to be the first bold paragraph

Tags: templates, abstract, documentclass

I am using overleaf for my text and want the Abstract as a first paragraph of the document in bold rather than a separate section on top.

I am using the following document class. Can some help me with this.

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,twocolumn,a4paper,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-2}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't use `\begin{abstract}` and `\end{abstract}`, and start the paper with `\bfseries` (which switches the font to bold), then the abstract, and then `\normalfont` (which switches the font back to normal).

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,twocolumn,a4paper,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\author{John Doe}
\title{Abstracts should be more concrete}
\maketitle
\bfseries Abstract: \lipsum[1]
\section{introduction}
\normalfont \lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want the first line of the abstract to be indented then you can use:

```
\bfseries\noindent Abstract: [...]
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks alot.